# Is it possible to generate 0 to 100 as selection for select_tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the input field just like this code now.
But I want to make select tag in which I can choose the number from 0 up to 100.
Is there any way to generate that select tag easily?

```
<%= f.number_field :age %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like below:

```
<%= f.select :age, (0..100).to_a.map{|n| [n, n]} %>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select("user[]", "age", 0..100.to_a.map{|n| [n, n]}, {}, { :index => nil })
```

or

```
f.select :age, options_for_select( 0..100.to_a.map{|n| [n, n]}, @object.age )
```

Comment: get rid of your array and use (1..100).to_a. Rails will do the string conversion

Answer (score 1):

```
 <%= f.select("person", "age", [1..100], { :include_blank => true })%>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= f.select :age, options_for_select((0..100).to_a) %>
```

Comment: Please provide some exmplanation of what is happening here - don't just post code.